# Errors/Problems using Xdocument.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-8

When I try to parse the XML document called "voicecmd.xml", located in the root of the solution, not in any folder, I recieve a **System.Xml.XmlException**. Why would this occur? My XML file is located below the code causing the error.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("/voicecmd.xml");
```

And the XML:

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/wm6RfJG1)

Was too large to post here. The other commandSets not expanded are copies for different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Load` method instead of `Parse`.
`Parse` method loads XML as string, while `Load` loads it from file.